# How to add moving lines on load-up website?

Tags: html, css

Gyazo: https://gyazo.com/015425f0decb187e28b620c1e3206391
Problem: https://gyazo.com/dfcd33e8a4fd5bea64e51fe40556f0bf

So I'm working on a website and I had this really nice idea to have 2 lines across the screen when you load up the website. Well, I got all of that working but everything else I add follows the lines so I think the code isn't how it should be. So my question is: How do I make 2 lines across the screen without having to put everything else with position: absolute. (I hope the code explains it better than me)

I've played around with lots of things but I can't figure it out.

```css
#horizontal-line {
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-animation: increase 2s;
  -moz-animation: increase 2s;
  animation: increase 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  float: left;
}

@keyframes increase {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#vertical-line {
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-animation: increaseV 2s;
  -moz-animation: increaseV 2s;
  animation: increaseV 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-top: -120px;
}

@keyframes increaseV {
  100% {
    height: 850px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-line"></div>
<div id="vertical-line"></div>
```

I hope someone knows a better way to have lines cross each other or knows what's wrong in the code. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that, the lines you've added are in the same "level"(z-index) of the rest of the page content. To avoid this, you could set the `z-index` of the lines to 1, and set the position to fixed. To the vertical line, you need to add the `right: 0` property, to move it to the right;

```css
#horizontal-line {
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-animation: increase 2s;
  -moz-animation: increase 2s;
  animation: increase 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes increase {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#vertical-line {
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-animation: increaseV 2s;
  -moz-animation: increaseV 2s;
  animation: increaseV 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -120px;
}

@keyframes increaseV {
  100% {
    height: 850px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-line"></div>
<div id="vertical-line"></div>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

```
#horizontal-line {
height: 0px;
width: 2px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
-webkit-animation: increase 2s;
-moz-animation: increase 2s;
animation: increase 2s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
float: left;
}
```